# Filter HtmlWebResponseObject for string in Content field returns whole field

Tags: powershell

I try to fetch only specific rows starting with 1 from a CSV file, however when I pipe the Content into the Select-String method it returns me the whole set. When I write it out to a file and pipe it into the select-string method it works.

```
C:> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.zamg.ac.at/ogd/" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content | Select-String -Pattern "1.*"
```

Comment: You dont need to expand the Property content. You can just use `convertfrom-csv` and then parse it however you wish to by piping it to `Select-Object`

Comment: We're almost there. If I do ``` Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.zamg.ac.at/ogd/" | ConvertFrom-csv -Delimiter ";" | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" | Select-String -Pattern "1.*" ``` then it returns me the csv, however it appends two newlines at the end and one at the start. how do I get rid of that?

Comment: You can replace the new lines using the answer. Cant mention in comment because baktick is taking as a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the new lines with nothing by using:

```
.replace('`r`n','')
```